# How to use macro with parameter in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to write following Objective-C statements in Swift language?

```
#define getStoryboard(StoryboardWithName) [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",StoryboardWithName, iPadDevice ? @"iPad" : @"iPhone"] bundle:NULL]
#define loadViewController(StoryBoardName, VCIdentifer) [getStoryboard(StoryBoardName)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:VCIdentifer]
```

Also let me know how to call this macros as we use following statement in Objective C

```
SecondVC *rc = loadViewController(@"Main_", @"IDSecondVC");
                          [self.navigationController pushViewController:rc animated:YES];
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using macros instead of functions to begin with. Macros provide absolutely no type safety and make debugging a nightmare. Always use a function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define functions in `Constant .swift` file

```
static func isIpad( ) ->Bool{
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .Phone:
        return false
    case .Pad:
        return true
    case .Unspecified:
        return false

    default :
        return false
    }
}

static func getStoryboard(storyboardName: String) -> UIStoryboard {
   return UIStoryboard(name: "\(storyboardName)\(Constants.isIpad() ? "iPad" : "iPhone")", bundle: nil)
}

static func loadVC(strStoryboardId: String, strVCId: String) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = getStoryboard(strStoryboardId).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(strVCId)
    return vc
}
```

Call function like this

```
 let vc = loadVC("Main", strVCId: "SecondViewController")
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
```

Answer (score 2):

macros are not supported in swift, what you can do is create a class method may be in Utils like this

```
func getStoryboard(storyboardName: String) -> UIStoryboard {
  return UIStoryboard(name: "\(storyboardName)\(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad ? "iPad" : "iPhone")", bundle: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried it other way

```
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {
        case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
        case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
        case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return "iPad Pro"
        case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
        case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
        default:                                        return identifier
        }
    }

}
```

//------------------------------------------------

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let deviceName = UIDevice()
        print(deviceName.modelName)
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: As asked sir, it returns all device which affected.

Comment: No, the question has nothing to do with getting the device identifier. You seem to be answering the wrong question.